# How do I get sufficient detail in planning and estimation when using TDD?

Tags: tdd, agile, estimation, targetprocess

When planning a 2-week iteration in the past I have taken a user story:

- Story: Rename a file

And broken it into tasks which were then estimated in hours:

- Story: Rename a file

  - Task: Create Rename command (2h)
  - Task: Maintain a list of selected files (3h)
  - Task: Hook up to F2 key (1h)
  - Task: Add context menu option (1h)

I would then pick a task to work on, and track the time spent on working on it. I would then repeat the process with another task. At the end of the iteration I could look at the time spent on each task, compare it to the estimation and use this information to improve future estimations.

When working entirely driven by tests, the only work that is clearly defined ahead of time are the acceptance tests that kicks off development and, on a user story that covers a large amount of work, the scope of an acceptance test can be too broad to give a good estimation.

So I can take a guess at the tasks that will end up being completed (as before), but the time spent on them is far more difficult to track as the tests make you work in tiny vertical slices, often working on a bit of each task at the same time.

Are there any techniques I could employ to give more detailed estimations and accurately track time when performing TDD? I am using [TargetProcess](http://www.targetprocess.com) which encourages splitting of user stories into tasks as outlined above, so keeping things in that format would be helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify what bearing TDD has on your estimation problems?

Comment: Because I no longer complete tasks one at a time it is more difficult to estimate and measure the time spent on each task. With TDD you tend to work on tiny slices of all of the tasks at the same time.

Comment: Well, don't do that!  With TDD and OOP you should be able to write each part in isolation.  Use interfaces to decouple all the tasks.

Comment: Of course the "parts" are decoupled with interfaces but the *tasks* are not. For each story I'm starting with an acceptance test (which drives the UI) to kick off the whole process, including discovery of the parts.

(See http://www.mockobjects.com/book/index.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4):

In agile both tasks and estimates are fluid things that change all the time.

So you might start with (bear in mind that these are very loose examples):

> - Story: Rename a file
>
>   - Task: Investigate Problem and break down (0d/5d)

First developer/s pick up that task and break it down as they go:

> - Story: Rename a file
>
>   - Task: Investigate Problem and break down (4h/complete)
>   - Task: 1st part (0d/2d)
>   - Task: 2nd part (0d/3d)

Then as they progress these updates get more accurate. New tasks get added and split out as they emerge:

> - Story: Rename a file
>
>   - Task: Investigate Problem and break down (4h/complete)
>   - Task: 1st part (4h/7h)
>   - Task: 2nd part (1h/20h)
>   - Task: new task realised while working on x (0h/5h)

It doesn't matter whether you are using Scrum, Crystal, XP, TDD or any other agile variant - they all rely on fluid estimations.

The fact is that you never know how long something is going to take - you just take your best guess and *revise it every day*. You'll never get a process where there are no surprises, but with agile you manage their impact.

For instance suppose something nasty comes up:

> - Story: Rename a file
>
>   - Task: Investigate Problem and break down (4h/complete)
>   - Task: 1st part (10h/complete)
>   - Task: 2nd part (10h/3h)
>   - Task: new task realised while working on x (3h/1h)
>   - **Task: resolve messy issue found while working on y (0h/5d)**

The story is now taking longer than expected, but everyone knows about it and knows why and you can handle it.

Your tasks and their estimates are constantly changing as the work gets done. A burndown chart is a good indicator of how much is left to do across the team. I wouldn't bother with velocity, but if you do it compares the 'amount done' between different iterations, giving you some idea of a project's momentum. Velocity only works when you have very consistent iteration lengths, team size and classification (size, difficulty, complexity etc) of stories, so I'd start with getting the burndown right each iteration and then move on to it.

Comment: So, in a nutshell, don't do it when planning the sprint, do it during the sprint?

That sounds OK, but when working in iterations it helps to nail down exactly what is in and what is out and try to stick to what was agreed before the iteration started. I'd worry that the team isn't thinking things through enough when planning the sprint - in the past, breaking a story into tasks which are then estimated in hours at the start has been reasonably accurate and uncovered problems before work has started. We are missing this with TDD.

Comment: With TDD the 'thinking things through' happens when deciding on the acceptance test. You have a clear idea of how you know when the feature is complete and rough idea of how long it will take. If you want the opportunity to check that the tasks are being properly thought out as they progress you can use daily meetings (or just sit down with the relevant team members each day or two) to check the detail. You can also make coding standards, review and design part of the acceptance test.

Answer (score 1):

We at TargetProcess use simpler tasks for stories:

Story: Rename a file

- Task: Specification (2h)
- Task: Development (14h)
- Task: Testing (6)
- Task: User Documentation update (2h)

If Development task takes more than 16 hrs, it is a sign to split it to several smaller tasks. In fact we don't usually create tasks with less than 2-3 h duration.